# What does net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING mean and how may I resolve it?

Tags: php, html, asp.net, httprequest, bing-api

I am writing a web application that generates a report from Bing Ads API, following the example seen here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-reporting-request-and-download-a-keyword-performance-report-in-php.aspx

I have the code compiled, however when running, the server abruptly ends the request and returns ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING right at the beginning of this code block:

```
$waitTime = 30 * 1; 
$reportRequestStatus = null;

// This sample polls every 30 seconds up to 5 minutes.
// In production you may poll the status every 1 to 2 minutes for up to one hour.
// If the call succeeds, stop polling. If the call or 
// download fails, the call throws a fault.

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    sleep($waitTime);

    // PollGenerateReport helper method calls the corresponding Bing Ads service operation
    // to get the report request status.

    $reportRequestStatus = PollGenerateReport(
            $proxy, 
            $reportRequestId
            );

    if ($reportRequestStatus->Status == ReportRequestStatusType::Success ||
        $reportRequestStatus->Status == ReportRequestStatusType::Error)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I have tried to print out values and debug it line by line, but I cannot figure out what's causing this error. Googling the error doesn't bring up anything relevant either. I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this error before, and could tell me what is causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im not mistaken - this is due to how you server is configured to handle various requests.

ASP.NET has some configuration settings but in a nutshell if you flush the buffer before the chunked request completes, you'll get this error. Here's a link I found some time ago when I ran into a similar problem. Good Luck!

Edit: Additionally here is an IIS page that describes how to enable the response handling that might be causing your issue:
Enable or disable HTTP 1.1 chunked transfer encoding

> To enable HTTP 1.1 chunked transfer encoding for the World Wide Web
>   publishing service, use the following syntax: appcmd set config
>   /section:asp /enableChunkedEncoding:True|False True enables HTTP 1.1
>   chunked transfer encoding whereas False disables HTTP 1.1 chunked
>   transfer encoding. The default value is True.
>
> ..
>
> and
>
> To specify the default length of time that ASP pages let a script run
>   before terminating the script and writing an event to the Windows
>   Event Log, use the following syntax: appcmd set config /section:asp
>   /scriptTimeout: timeSpan The variable timeSpan represents the maximum
>   time (hh:mm:ss) that an ASP request can run before an event is written
>   to the Windows Event Log. The default value is 00:01:30.
>   [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730855(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730855%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

also this guys explains it very well :

> > ASP.NET transfers the data to the client in chunked encoding (Transfer-Encoding: chunked), if you prematurely flush the Response
> >     stream for the Http request and the Content-Length header for the
> >     Response is not explicitly set by you.
>
> Normally this should not be a problem because most modern HTTP clients
>   are capable of handling both chunked as well as non-chunked server
>   responses, de-chunking the chunked response automatically (Note that
>   Chunked transfer encoding is defined only by HTTP 1.1 specification).
>
> However, in my own case, I was making an asynchronous Ajax call to an
>   ASP.NET web-service from javascript. And the web-method handling the
>   request flushed the Response explicitly to the client, and then closed
>   the Response (I needed to do so, because the request was issued from
>   an auto-load call of an ExtJs store, and I needed to close the
>   connection on the server for the client-side Store to accept and load
>   the json serialized data).
>
> http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/06/asp-net-sets-the-transfer-encoding-as-chunked-on-premature-flushing-the-response

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. Is the solution quite trivial?

Comment: Some what - it just required some reading about more of the innerworkings of IIS that i wanted to know at the time but hey - it builds character right?

Comment: I am not longer getting an `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` anymore, so modifying the `Content-Length` does 'solve' that particular error. However, now I am getting a `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`, any suggestions?

Comment: just updated my answer with some more information. Essentially its a comingled result of settings that you will need to look at and evaluate on your end what works best for your environment and application(s).

Comment: Thanks again, this definitely gives some material to work with for a solution. I'll see what I come up with and will let you know the result!

Comment: The issue was indeed a server configuration issue. Although I did not find what specifically caused the issue, moving to a new server resolved everything. Thank you for your help!